# Perfect square as sum and difference of powers of 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a positive integer, and

$$3^{2017}-3^{2016}-3^{2015}+3^{2014}+3^{n+(-1)^n}$$

is a perfect square, find the value of $n$. I am completely lost on this. Do I factor out some factors of $3$?

Comment: Hint: Convert the Left $4$ terms into the form $16 \times k^2.$  Then, consider that $9 + 16 = 25.$  Therefore, if you can convert the rightmost term into $9 \times k^2$, then the sum will be $k^2(16 + 9)$.

Comment: So I get $3^{2014}(16)+3^{n+(-1)^n}=k^2$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where does $16 \times k^2$ come from

Comment: $\displaystyle 3^{2014} = \left[3^{1007}\right]^2.$

Comment: Is that the only way to get a perfect square?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Unknown.  There are two pieces of evidence that may be inconclusive.  The first is meta-cheating: the statement "find the value of n" suggests that $n$ is unique.  The second point is that you have to satisfy $16 \times 3^{14} + 3^r = k^2 ~: r,k \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$  Personally, I find the second point *merely suggestive*.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Typo in previous comment, should be "...$16 \times 3^{2014} +$ ..."

Comment: that makes sense that's what I get $16 \times 3^{2014} +3^r=k^2$ where $r=n+(-1)^n$

Comment: where do I go from there ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the hints, $$3^{2017}-3^{2016}-3^{2015}+3^{2014} +3^{n+(-1)^n} = 16×3^{2014}+3^{n+(-1)^n}.$$ $$=(4×3^{1007})^2 +3^{n+(-1)^n}.$$ So we next solve for $n$ and $a$:
$$(4×3^{1007} + a)^2$$ $$ = 16×3^{2014}+3^{n+(-1)^n}.$$

Calculating out the square on the LHS and subtracting $16×3^{2014}$ from both sides yields
$$8a×3^{1007} + a^2$$  $$= (8×3^{1007}+a)a = 3^{n+(-1)^n}.$$
Now, as the LHS $(8×3^{1007})a$ of this simultaneously on the one hand must be a power of $3$ i.e., no other prime factors besides $3$, and on the other hand is also a multiple of $a$. So it follows that $a$ must itself be a power of $3$ so write $a=3^k$. As $(8×3^{1007}+a)$ $=(8×3^{1007}+3^k)$ must also be a power of $3$, it follows that $k$ must be $1007$ and so $a$ must satisfy $a=3^{1007}$. [Indeed if $k <1007$ then the largest power of $3$ dividing $8×3^{1007}+3^k$ will be only $3^k$ but $8+3^{1007}+3^k$ is strictly larger than $3^{1007}>3^k$ so it cannot be a power of $3$ after all. If $k >1007$ then the largest power of $3$ dividing $8×3^{1007}+3^k$ is only $3^{1007}$ but $8×3^{1007}+3^k$ is strictly larger than $3^{1007}$ so it can't be a power of $3$ either.]Thus:

$$(4×3^{1007}+3^{1007})^2=25×3^{2014}$$ $$=(16×3^{2014})+(9×3^{2014})$$ $$=(3^{2017}-3^{2016}-3^{2015} +3^{2014})$$ $$ + (9×3^{2014}).$$
So $3^{n+(-1)^n} = 9×3^{2014}$ $=3^{2016}$. So $n+(-1)^n =2016$, which gives $n=2017$.